# Subquery with multiple averages

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, aggregate-functions

I've been struggling with a problem that goes something like this, "Find all employees with a salary greater than the average salary of their department." My sql subquery lumps all the departments salaries together to make one average salary but I need a way to get the each individual department's average salary.

My sql statement looks like this.

```
SELECT EmployeeName
FROM dbo.EMP
WHERE Salary > (
        SELECT AVG(Salary)
        FROM dbo.EMP
        )
GROUP BY DeptNo
```

Comment: are you sure that you're using microsoft sql-server? maybe mysql?

Comment: `dbo` seems very MS-ish

Comment: @JNevill dbo - yes, but selecting column which is not in group by - allowed only by mysql in non-strict mode

Comment: Oh man... that's true. I hate that functionality of `mysql` with a passion. It's just evil.

Answer (score 2):

You can just finish off that subquery to make it a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT EmployeeName
FROM dbo.EMP as t1
WHERE Salary > (
        SELECT AVG(Salary)
        FROM dbo.EMP
        WHERE dbo.EMP.DeptNo = t1.DeptNo
        )
```

Alternatively you could use Window Functions:

```
SELECT
    EmployeeName,
    CASE WHEN Salary > AVG(Salary) OVER (PARTITION BY DeptNo) Then 'X' END as [HigherThanAverage]
FROM dbo.EMP
```

That will give you all employees and an indicator if their salary is higher than their department's average, which you could filter out later on. I figured I'd stick this in here since it gives you some options as the scale of your query grows.

Comment: you cannot select non-aggregated columns which are not in group by

Comment: I removed the `GROUP BY` since it wasn't doing anything anyway. That was just copy-pasta from OP's attempt.

Answer (score 2):

here is quick variant:

```
select EmployeeName
from 
dbo.EMP as a
inner join
(
SELECT DeptNo, AVG(Salary) as avgSalary
FROM dbo.EMP
GROUP BY DeptNo
) as b
on (a.DeptNo=b.DeptNo and a.Salary > b.avgSalary)
```